# TimerTask for Reconnecting in splash screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-task, android-timer

I have splashScreen with some startup requests where data are loaded into the app. Before I initiate those splashScreen requests, I want to check connection. This part is working fine, but if app doesn't have access to the internet, I want to check connection every 2 seconds. If connection is established, I want to cancel `Timer/TimerTask` and execute code under `Timer` call(hiding reconnecting progressBar and Text and call server api again). But if I run this code below, app will crash without any error visible in Logcat. But I can see Reconnecting Log from TimerTask still running.

I've tried to move `api.splashScreen(this)` and `hideReconnectViews()` into the ReconnectCheck class and call those via context, but this throw exception:

> android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Any ideas why my solution doesn't work?

Code in SplashScreen activity:

```
const val RECONNECT_TIME: Long = 2000

if(isOnline()){
            api.splashScreen(this)
        } else {
            showReconnectViews()
            val reconnectTimer = Timer()
            reconnectTimer.schedule(ReconnectCheck(this, reconnectTimer), 0, RECONNECT_TIME)
            createLog("ReconnectCheck ", "TimerFinished")
            api.splashScreen(this)
            hideReconnectViews()
        }
```

ReconnectCheck class:

```
class ReconnectCheck(val ctx: Context, val timer: Timer): TimerTask() {

    override fun run() {
        if ((ctx as Splash).isOnline()){
            timer.cancel()
            timer.purge()
        } else {
            Log.i("ReconnectCheck: ", "Reconnecting")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your run method is executed on a different thread than the main thread. Get the main thread and change your views there. But anyway, usually it is not a good idea to do such operations using timers. Let the user decide to try again, use a service or use viewmodels.

Answer (score 0):

Your run method is executed on a different thread than the main thread. Get the main thread and change your views there.
[@JacksOnF1re](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2607567/jacksonf1re)

Code:

```
class ReconnectCheck(val ctx: Context, val timer: Timer): TimerTask() {
    private val api: API = API.getInstance(ctx)

    override fun run() {
        if ((ctx as Splash).isOnline()){
            ctx.runOnUiThread {
                ctx.hideReconnectViews()
                api.splashScreen(ctx)
            }
            timer.cancel()
            timer.purge()
        } else {
            Log.i("ReconnectCheck: ", "Reconnecting")
        }
    }
}
```

This worked.